# Swift, Pass data back from popover to view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, popover

I have sorted the original array in popover controller. Now I want to send that array back to the original view controller for tableview and map view.

### Below is my code

```
 If propertyNameSrt == false
    {
        if ascSorting == false
        {
            properties.sort(sorterForbuildingAsc)
        }
        else
        {
            properties.sort(sorterForbuildingDesc)
        }


    }
```

My array is properties which includes custom object.
How can pass this to my original view controller?
Thanks in advance,
Dhaval.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use delegate(protocol) methods to send back data to previous view controller.

IN CURRENT VC:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class
{
    func sendArrayToPreviousVC(myArray:[AnyObject])
}
```

Make a var in your class.

```
weak var mDelegate:MyProtocol?
```

Now call the protocol method when you pop the view controller, with your "properties" array as parameter.

```
mDelegate?.sendArrayToPreviousVC(properties)
```

IN PREVIOUS VC:

In your previous VC, set the mDelegate property to self, when you push the current VC.

```
currentVC.mDelegate = self
//PUSH VC
```

Now implement the protocol method in your previous VC.

```
func sendArrayToPreviousVC(myArray:[AnyObject]) {
    //DO YOUR THING
}
```

Comment: Have little question..var mDelegate:MyProtocol? (will be difine in popviewcontroller?) or previous controller?

Comment: in the popviewcontroller

Comment: ok @Thijs ..so how can i define this (currentVC.mDelegate = self) in my original view controller? sorry for bothering you

Comment: ohh , i have messed up little bit...insteadof uiPopovercontroller i have created uiviewcontroller..

Comment: @Thijs   thanks for the lovely code...if in popover i have used viewcontroller. So will it create a issue?

Comment: Haven't worked with those popovers myself, and without the rest of your code I don't know which view controller you should use. The gist was only meant to show where to put the delegate code. Should have mentioned this before, sorry -_-

Comment: btw ..i have changes the code a little bit...and it worked..thanks @Thijis

Comment: delegate should be a weak reference

Comment: Previous VC should implement **MyProtocol**  `PreviousVC: UIViewController, MyProtocol `